# Option<T> where T can be two different traits?

Tags: traits, rust

If I have two different traits:

```
trait Foo {}
trait Bar {}
```

is it then possible to have a Option which can be either of them (or None, of course), like:

```
struct FooBar {
  fb: Option<~Foo or Bar>
}

let fb1 = FooBar{fb: Some(~somestruct as ~Foo)}
let fb2 = FooBar{fb: Some(~otherstruct as ~Bar)}
```

and  have them both work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about `Option<T>`; it is simply this, plus some convenience methods and a bit of documentation:

```rust
pub enum Option<T> {
    Some(T),
    None,
}
```

Bear this in mind: it's enums all the way. You can make your own enums. It will certainly be explicit, but learn to appreciate that as a good thing.

```rust
pub enum FooOrBar {
    Foo(~Foo),
    Bar(~Bar),
}
```

You can make an `Option<T>` of *this*. Or perhaps you would prefer to blend the two, if you can get better semantic meaning out of it:

```rust
pub enum Something {
    Foozy(~Foo),
    Bark(~Bar),
    ADifferentVariant,
}
```

Comment: Works great! Enums all the way down. I must admit I've never used a language  with enums before so I'm still working on groking them.